# react component method binding with arrow function (class properties)

Tags: reactjs

I heard that this is the cool way to define function instead of binding them in constructor:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
    delete = id => {

    }

    render() {}
}
```

but when I try to build I get:

Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (7:15)

pointing to equal sign after delete

what I am missing?

Comment: You're probably missing babel (a transpiler that converts newer javascript to older javascript). That syntax isn't in the standard but it exists as a proposal I believe.

Comment: I have babel. But then I believe question is when it got in specs and is this approved in some escmascript release? I even don't know how to google this.

Comment: You are missing the https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties plugin, `create-react-app` includes it by default, at least in the actual version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define class properties the way you are doing it, you need to **activate the experimental babel feature [`transform-class-properties`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)**. This allows you to assign expressions like arrrow functions to class properties:

```
class Bork {
    //Property initializer syntax
    instanceProperty = "bork";
    boundFunction = () => {
      return this.instanceProperty;
    }

    //Static class properties
    static staticProperty = "babelIsCool";
    static staticFunction = function() {
      return Bork.staticProperty;
    }
  }
```

---

Note that [this feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is **not yet part of the ECMAScript specification** and may change in the future.

Comment: Good note that this is not in specs. I kinda expected that.

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional babel plugin for this feature:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties